# Any idea how I can schedule the batch class after 7 days

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

I was trying this Cron statement but it's not working.Any idea how I can make it run.

0 0 23 1/7 * ? *

Comment: Are you saying you want to run the batch 7 days after today's date, and only run it once?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one through Schedule Apex also.

Steps are as followed:

**Apex Classes --> Schedule Apex**

Check the screen short to understand.

[image]

Comment: I am using another batch to set date and then hoping to run another batch just after 7 days

Comment: Any other way from which we can achieve this

Comment: I Guess No other methods @SalesforceThings

Answer (score 0):

Go to these links, and you want to choose after 7 days then choose here weekly and choose date today day.

[image: see]http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score -1):

Please use these CRON Expression ----> `0 0 23 9 * ? *`

0----> Seconds

0 ---> Minutes

23---> Hours

9 ---> Date (Add 7 Days)